# Select from multiple tables with different columns

Tags: sql, inheritance, database-design

Say I got this SQL schema.

Table Job:

```
id,title, type, is_enabled
```

Table JobFileCopy:

```
job_id,from_path,to_path
```

Table JobFileDelete:

```
job_id, file_path
```

Table JobStartProcess:

```
job_id, file_path, arguments, working_directory
```

There are many other tables with varying number of columns and they all got foreign key job_id which is linked to id in table Job.

My questions:
Is this the right approach? I don't have requirement to delete anything at anytime. I will require to select and insert mostly.

Secondly, what is the best approach to get the list of jobs with relevant details from all the different tables in a single database hit? e.g I would like to select top 20 jobs with details, their details can be in any table (depends on column type in table Job) which I don't know until runtime.

Comment: What do you mean by 'top 20'? What is the measure you wanna sort the jobs with?

Comment: Top 20 was just an example. The Job table will have a few more columns e.g when_added, when_started, user_id etc etc. Say I filter based on those columns and get the top 20 (or any other number) rows from table Job which is no issue at all. The main issue is how can I get the job details, which are stored in other tables?

Comment: Why a simple join select or a view is not enough for your requirements!?

Comment: Well I can join if I know before hand what I'll be fetching. As I said I won't know which table has got the details for the job. I get the basic info about the job from job table and rest of the details are fetched from other tables (based on type of job).

Answer (score 0):

```
select (case when type = 'type1' then (select field from table1) else (select field from table2) end) as a from table;
```

Could it be a solution for you?